# Changing GUI visibility using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am new in GUI Programming. I am using Visual Studio (C++). What I wanted to ask is: Is there a way to make the parent window invisible when a dialog box is launched from the main window? Also, how to make the window reappear on exiting from the dialog box?

Comment: This isn't about C++ in general, but more about Win32 (and potentially MFC).  It also doesn't demonstrate any attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking to do isn't very good UI design, as it can cause confusion for the user when windows inexplicably start disappearing.

What you're probably trying to do is bring the user's attention to the dialog box and force them to use it before allowing them back to the main window. This is already achieved by making the dialog box a modal dialog box - note that there's a distinction between a dialog and a window. A dialog will not allow input in the parent window.

Comment: A **modal** dialog box will not allow the user to input in the parent window.  A **modeless** dialog box will.

Comment: Wanted to write the same, but here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx) for clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using MFC and a modal dialog then you could do the following:

```
mainWindow.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
dialog.DoModal();
mainWindow.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

---

*Regarding to the comments, here is a modeless solution:*

YourDialog.h

```
class YourDialog : public CDialog {
    CWnd& _mainWindowToHide;
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();
    void OnShowWindow(BOOL bShow, UINT nStatus);
    virtual void OnOK();
    virtual void OnCancel();
public:
    YourDialog(CWnd& mainWindowToHide);
};
```

YourDialog.cpp

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(YourDialog, CDialog)
   ON_WM_SHOWWINDOW()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

YourDialog::YourDialog(CWnd& mainWindowToHide) 
    : _mainWindowToHide(mainWindowToHide) { }

void YourDialog::OnShowWindow(BOOL bShow, UINT nStatus) {
    if(bShow == TRUE)
        _mainWindowToHide.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    CDialog::OnShowWindow(bShow, nStatus);
}

void YourDialog::OnOK() {
    _mainWindowToHide.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    CDialog::OnOK();
}

void YourDialog::OnCancel() {
    _mainWindowToHide.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    CDialog::OnCancel();
}
```

Whereever you want to use this:

```
dialogMember = new YourDialog(mainWindow);
dialogMember->Create(IDD_YOUR_DIALOG);
dialogMember->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: This does not do what you think. If you hide a window, this also hides all owned windows.

Comment: Well, who says that the dialog is owned by the parent window?

Comment: You called `DoModal`. This implies a modal dialog. A modal dialog without an owner window does not make a whole lot of sense. And since it's called `parentWindow` it would be a far stretch to say it isn't.

Comment: So you're complaining about the naming? Okay fair point. But DoModal does block further execution of the function which makes it easier to show the **main window** again. Otherwise you must overwrite OnOK and OnCancel to show the **main window** again.

Comment: That's the whole point: If you do not have an owner window, you're not blocking an owner window. If you do have an owner window, hiding that owner implicitly hides the owned window (your dialog). In essence, you have not provided a solution.

Comment: I was not talking about blocking the window (including window interaction)!

Comment: You have to make up your mind. You cannot call `DoModal` and keep saying that you didn't mean to disable the owner window. You just did.